# How to join 4 tables in SQL not connected with each other by 1 ID?

Tags: sql, join

I have question about joining 4 tables from below graph:

[image: graph]

I have tried to do this like that:

```sql
SELECT (something)
FROM Employee_Territories as et
INNER JOIN Employees as e
    ON et.employeeID=e.employeeID
INNER JOIN Territories as t
    ON et.territoryID=t.territoryID
```

but what's next? I don't know how to put here connection between Region and Territories by RegionID. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring in `Region` from the `Territories` table, using `RegrionID` as the joining column:

```
SELECT (something)
FROM 
    Employee_Territories as et
    INNER JOIN Employees as e
        ON et.employeeID = e.employeeID
    INNER JOIN Territories as t
        ON et.territoryID = t.territoryID
    INNER JOIN Region as r
        ON r.regionID = t.regionID
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't see this relation at my first glance :)